# How to add border on gridlayout

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm trying to add borders to this nativescript `GridLayout` usig the `gridStyle`

```xml
<GridLayout columns="200, 150" rows="15, 20" class="gridStyle">
  <label text="Patient Name" class="rowLabelStyle" row="0" col="0"/>
  <label text="{{ fullName }}" class="rowDataStyle" row="1" col="0"/>
  <label text="DOB" class="rowLabelStyle" row="0" col="1"/>
  <label text="{{ data.subDateOfBirth }}" class="rowDataStyle" row="1" col="1"/>
</GridLayout>
```

and here is the relevant css

```css
.gridStyle {
    background-color: cadetblue;
    border: solid 1px darkgray ;
}
```

I have look in many places, tutorial, the official documentation without much luck, the table will not show any orders are all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NativeScript supported CSS properties are `border-width`, `border-color` and `border-radius`. `border` tag alone would not work.

HTML

```js
<GridLayout columns="200, 150" rows="15, 20" class="gridStyle">
  <label text="Patient Name" class="rowLabelStyle" row="0" col="0"/>
  <label text="{{ fullName }}" class="rowDataStyle" row="1" col="0"/>
  <label text="DOB" class="rowLabelStyle" row="0" col="1"/>
  <label text="{{ data.subDateOfBirth }}" class="rowDataStyle" row="1" col="1"/>
</GridLayout>
```

CSS

```css
.gridStyle {
  border-color: cadetblue;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

More info:
https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling

Comment: that style "GridLayout" does not have to be mentioned anywhere in the HTML right ? we are overriding the defult style

Comment: Made the changes, please have a look.

Comment: is working, I just added "px" to the width, thanks so much.